# How to save an image to FileField from its path?

Tags: python, django, file, django-views

I have an **image** stored in my `media/logo/` folder and I'd like to save it to my model's `FileField` from my view. Here's what I tried but I'm getting an encoding error & the file becomes corrupted after I'm trying to save it.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte ...

---

**views.py:**

```
def save_records(request):
    new_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'logo', filename)
    same_file = File(new_path, filename)
    Company.objects.create(logo=same_file)
```

I have some trouble understanding how I can save the file in `new_path` to the FileField, any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want FileField to use an existing file instead of creating a new one.

```
def save_records(request):
    c = Company()
    c.logo.name = 'logo/<filename>'  #relative to the media root.
    c.save()
```

And, if you want to modify the filename of an existing record

```
old_path = c.logo.path
c.logo.name = 'logo/<new filename>'  #relative to the media root.
new_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + c.logo.name
os.rename(old_path, new_path)
c.save()
```

If you want to copy the contents to a new file, then use @Roman Miroshnychenko's solution.

Django's FileField internally uses [FileSystemStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage) to store and mangae the files, So you can override its behavior. This will make sure Django always uses file name supplied, instead of generating new one.

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

class CustomFileStorage(FileSystemStorage):

    def get_available_name(self, name):
        return name # returns the same name
```

In your models

```
from app.storage import CustomFileStorage

fs = CustomFileStorage()

class Company(models.Model):
   logo = model.FileField(storage=fs)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/files/file/) `File` class expects a file object as the 1st argument, not a path string. You need to do:

```
with open(new_path, 'rb') as fo:
    same_file = File(fo, filename)
    Company.objects.create(logo=same_file)
```

Comment: The problem is that the file already exists and django is saving a new one instead of taking the existing one, is there a way to not create a new file and take what already exists ?